# The code is printing the same values when it should be randomly generating each ovr and also it is not printing the first value in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, random

The issue that I am having is that with the code below, each `plOvr` for all of the class objects is the same. This causes them to have the same stats for everything. Also, I have an array with names that should be printed but it is skipping the first value.

```
using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:
    int plOvr;
    float plSpg, plSps;
    string werk;
    void setPlayeName(string);
    string plName;
    void setPlyrVal()
    {
        srand (time(NULL));
        plOvr = rand()% 29 + 70;
        plSps = plOvr / 10;
        plSpg = plSps / 2;
    }
};

void Player::setPlayeName(string werk)
{
 plName = werk;
}

int main()
{
    Player plyr1,plyr2,plyr3,plyr4,plyr5;
    string firstTime;
    string name[5] = {"Eric Gelinas","John Merill", "Jaromir Jagr", "Travis Zajac","Reid Boucher"};

    bool firstOp;

    cout << "Is this the first time this program has run?" << endl;
    cin >> firstTime;

    if (firstTime == "Yes" || firstTime == "yes")
    {
        firstOp == firstOp;
        plyr1.setPlyrVal();
        plyr1.setPlayeName(name[1]);
        plyr2.setPlyrVal();
        plyr2.setPlayeName(name[2]);
        plyr3.setPlyrVal();
        plyr3.setPlayeName(name[3]);
        plyr4.setPlyrVal();
        plyr4.setPlayeName(name[4]);
        plyr5.setPlyrVal();
        plyr5.setPlayeName(name[5]);
        ofstream playerSaveData;

        playerSaveData.open ("savedata.txt");

        playerSaveData << plyr1.plName << "," << plyr1.plOvr << "," << plyr1.plSpg << "," << plyr1.plSps << "\n";
        playerSaveData << plyr2.plName << "," << plyr2.plOvr << "," << plyr2.plSpg << "," << plyr2.plSps << "\n";
        playerSaveData << plyr3.plName << "," << plyr3.plOvr << "," << plyr3.plSpg << "," << plyr3.plSps << "\n";
        playerSaveData << plyr4.plName << "," << plyr4.plOvr << "," << plyr4.plSpg << "," << plyr4.plSps << "\n";
        playerSaveData << plyr5.plName << "," << plyr5.plOvr << "," << plyr5.plSpg << "," << plyr5.plSps << "\n";
        playerSaveData.close();

        cout << "done.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        firstOp == !firstOp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't seed rand more than once.

Comment: Use the utilities in `<random>` instead of `srand` and `rand`.

Comment: `string name[5]`'s element should be `name[0]` - `name[4]`, not `name[1]` - `name[5]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>` and an engine as `std::mt19937` from `<random>`. 
The engine (as `srand`) has to be initialized with seed only once.
Your program rewritten:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

class Player
{
public:
    void setPlayeName(const std::string& name) { plName = name; }
    void setPlyrVal(std::mt19937& rand_engine)
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(70, 98);
        plOvr = distr(rand_engine);
        plSps = plOvr / 10;
        plSpg = plSps / 2;
    }

public:
    int plOvr;
    float plSpg, plSps;
    std::string werk;
    std::string plName;
};

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rand_engine(time(nullptr));
    Player plyrs[5];
    const std::string names[5] = {"Eric Gelinas","John Merill", "Jaromir Jagr", "Travis Zajac","Reid Boucher"};

    std::cout << "Is this the first time this program has run?" << std::endl;
    std::string firstTime;
    std::cin >> firstTime;

    if (firstTime == "Yes" || firstTime == "yes") {
        for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
            plyrs[i].setPlyrVal(rand_engine);
            plyrs[i].setPlayeName(names[i]);
        }
        std::ofstream playerSaveData;

        playerSaveData.open ("savedata.txt");

        for (const auto& plyr : plyrs) {
            playerSaveData << plyr.plName << "," << plyr.plOvr << "," << plyr.plSpg << "," << plyr.plSps << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "done." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/hSkX56)

Answer (score 0):

You should call `srand()` only once in the whole program, instead of calling it before each `rand()`.